# constraints for a zero-one integer programming problem

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization

We want to arrange 8 tables in 2 rooms. How to write the following constraints?

- Either table 3 or table 6 must be in room 1 (or both).
- Exactly one of tables 7 and 8 must be in room 2.

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself? What variable definition did you come up with? And what constraints didn't work?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Please show your attempts and [use MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site) to support your formatting.

Answer (score 3):

With OPL CPLEX Mathematical Programming you can write

```
// We want to arrange 8 tables in 2 rooms.

range tables=1..8;
range rooms=1..2;

dvar boolean x[tables][rooms];

subject to
{
  
  forall(t in tables) sum(r in rooms) x[t][r]==1;

    //Either table 3 or table 6 must be in room 1 (or both).
    x[3][1]+x[6][1]>=1;
    
    //Exactly one of tables 7 and 8 must be in room 2.
    sum(t in 7..8) x[t][2]==1;
    
}   

{int} tablesPerRoom[r in rooms]={i | i in tables : x[i][r]==1};

execute
{
  writeln(tablesPerRoom);
}
```

which can give

```
[{1 2 3 4 5 6 8} {7}]
```

Within CPLEX you can also rely on Constraint Programming CPOptimizer. Then you can write "using CP"; at the beginning of the model.

Or within CPOptimizer you can rely on specific CP constraints and write

```
using CP;

// We want to arrange 8 tables in 2 rooms.

range tables=1..8;
range rooms=1..2;

dvar int x[tables] in rooms;

subject to
{
  
  

    //Either table 3 or table 6 must be in room 1 (or both).
    (x[6]==1)||(x[3]==1);
    
    //Exactly one of tables 7 and 8 must be in room 2.
    count(all(i in 7..8)x[i],2)==1;
    
}   



execute
{
  writeln(x);
}
```

which can give

```
[1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2]
```

Comment: Maybe I misinterpret your code, but shouldn't "either table 3 or table 6 goes in room 1 (or both)" be interpreted as $x_{3,1}+x_{6,1}\geq 1$?

Comment: Your are right and I read the English constraint too fast. I fixed the models